# How do I list all options a file system is mounted with?

Tags: mount, fstab

Both `mount` and `cat /proc/mounts` do not give me all the options I specified in the 'options' field in `/etc/fstab`.

For example, this is in my `/etc/fstab`:

```
# <file system>                                 <mount point>   <type>  <options>                                       <dump>  <pass>
UUID=1afaad96-8aa3-4283-95a4-20510e5b3fbb      /               ext4    rw,async,exec,nouser,suid,errors=remount-ro     0       1
```

But the output of `mount` just gives me this (`mount -v` doesn't work either):

```
/dev/sda6 on / type ext4 (rw)
```

And `cat /proc/mounts:

```
rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0
```

How can I check with what options my file systems are mounted?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that you are not understanding what "rootfs" means.

If you `cat /proc/mounts`, or filter the output with grep or awk, you do indeed get a list of all them mounts and the options as indicated by @steeldriver.

The first line, `rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0` is not your root partition, it is used by the kernel.

> ### What is rootfs?
>
> **Rootfs is a special instance of ramfs** (or tmpfs, if that's enabled), which is
>   always present in 2.6 systems.  You can't unmount rootfs for approximately the
>   same reason you can't kill the init process; rather than having special code
>   to check for and handle an empty list, it's smaller and simpler for the kernel
>   to just make sure certain lists can't become empty.
>
> **Most systems just mount another filesystem over `rootfs` and ignore it.**  The
>   amount of space an empty instance of `ramfs` takes up is tiny.
>
> If `CONFIG_TMPFS` is enabled, `rootfs` will use `tmpfs` instead of `ramfs` by
>   default.  To force `ramfs`, add "rootfstype=ramfs" to the kernel command
>   line.

See https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt

Look closer at the output, or filter the results with grep or awk

```
grep '/dev' /proc/mounts
```

Answer (score 6):

The `/proc/mounts` file should indeed contain the options (including default options for each filesystem), however the `rootfs` entry that you picked out is just a ramfs over which the actual root block device gets mounted - there should be another entry for the real device e.g.

```
$ mount | grep ' / '
/dev/mapper/t60p-root on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
```

```
$ grep ' / ' /proc/mounts
rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0
/dev/mapper/t60p-root / ext4 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0
```

Comment: Your information is correct, but, if you look at the question, the OP is asking about `rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0`